# Bootstrap/CSS - How to put various images over a long image (that is behind them)?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to put six .png images over a long, tray-like image. I don't know if my structure is wrong or if bootstrap is in conflict with CSS when I play around with `position: absolute` and `position: relative` (which I later removed). This is the result I expected:

[image]

However, this is my current status:

[image]

Here's my code.

HTML code:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row mt-2">
        <div class="">
            <img class="tray" src="../../../assets/images/Generals/Icon_1.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <img class="tray-icon" src="../../../assets/images/Generals/Icon_2.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <img class="tray-icon" src="../../../assets/images/Generals/Icon_3.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <img class="tray-icon" src="../../../assets/images/Generals/Icon_4.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <img class="tray-icon" src="../../../assets/images/Generals/Icon_5.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <img class="tray-icon" src="../../../assets/images/Generals/Icon_6.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <img class="tray-icon" src="../../../assets/images/Generals/Icon_7.png" alt="">
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.tray-icon{
    width: 70%;
    transition: transform .2s; 
}

.tray{
    width: 100%;
}

.tray-icon:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5); 
  }
```

Any idea how can I get closer to the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Given the info/code you've placed in your question:

- Give each image: `display: block;` so that they each moves to a new line.
- Center everything. Might be a mixture of `text-align: center;` which typically centers it's inline/inline-block children (unless over-ridden), or try using `margin: 0 auto;` which typically centers inline-block/block elements.
- At this point everything should be centered in `.d-flex.flex-row`. Move the dark blue image up into position by giving it a negative margin-top: `margin: -40px auto 0;`. You could also use `position: relative; top: -40px;`, or `transform: translateY(-40px);`. Pick your poison.

Your code should something like the example code I've attached below. Some rules won't apply as well, like box-shadow (if you're using on on an image for example).

```css
.d-flex.flex-row {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
/* this is the dark blue square. */
.d-flex.flex-row::after {
    content: "";
    background-image: url(https://imagecdn.app/v1/images/https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fphoto-1525923838299-2312b60f6d69?width=500&height=70);
    width: 500px;
    height: 70px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    margin: -40px auto 0;
    display: block;
    background-size: cover;
}

/* your image containers */
.d-flex.flex-row > div { 
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 2px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* your images */
.d-flex.flex-row > div img { 
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex flex-row mt-2">
  <div class="">
      <img class="tray" src="https://imagecdn.app/v1/images/https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fphoto-1525923838299-2312b60f6d69?width=50&height=50" alt="">
  </div>
    <div class="">
      <img class="tray" src="https://imagecdn.app/v1/images/https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fphoto-1525923838299-2312b60f6d69?width=50&height=50" alt="">
  </div>
    <div class="">
      <img class="tray" src="https://imagecdn.app/v1/images/https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fphoto-1525923838299-2312b60f6d69?width=50&height=50" alt="">
  </div>
    <div class="">
      <img class="tray" src="https://imagecdn.app/v1/images/https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fphoto-1525923838299-2312b60f6d69?width=50&height=50" alt="">
  </div>
    <div class="">
      <img class="tray" src="https://imagecdn.app/v1/images/https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fphoto-1525923838299-2312b60f6d69?width=50&height=50" alt="">
  </div>
    <div class="">
      <img class="tray" src="https://imagecdn.app/v1/images/https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fphoto-1525923838299-2312b60f6d69?width=50&height=50" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```